# Append table with Django URL tag JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I have a table I am appending with user details and want to add a Django URL tag to the row and grab the primary key in the tag.

something like this:

```
function putTableData(response) {
    let row;
    $("#table_body").html("");
    if (response["data"].length > 0) {
        $.each(response["data"], function (a, b) {
            row = `<tr>
                        <td>${b["first_name"]} ${b["last_name"]}</td                               
                        <td>${b["phone"]}</td>                   
                        <td>
                            <a onclick='console.log("${b["pk"]}")' data-url="{% url 'users:edit' user.${b["pk"]} %}">
                            </a>                     
                        </td>
                    </tr>`;

                $("#table_body").append(row)
```

The onclick console log is printing the users primary key, but when I try to add the data url tag, I get "Could not parse the remainder ${b["pk"]}

How would I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each(response["data"], function (a, b) {
    data_url = "{% url 'users:edit' 1 %}".replace(1, b["pk"])
    row = `<tr>
                    <td>${b["first_name"]} ${b["last_name"]}</td                               
                    <td>${b["phone"]}</td>                   
                    <td>
                        <a onclick='console.log("${b["pk"]}")' data-url="+data_url+">
                        </a>                     
                    </td>
                </tr>`;

    $("#table_body").append(row)
});
```

Comment: I tried that and I am getting uncaught syntax error. Table isn't loading.

Comment: Can you show the full error and check where it is occurring ?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. It is happening at data_url = "{% url 'users:edit' 1 %}".replace(1, ${b["pk"]})

Comment: Replace `${b["pk"]}` with `b["pk"]` in `data_url` variable.

Comment: The users load in the table now but the data_url variable isn't passing to the data-url .

Comment: Can you inspect and see what is the value of data-url attribute in the browser.

Comment: its getting data_url

Comment: Okay do this replace "`" with double quote and double quote with single quote but for data_url keep it as is (i.e: double quote with plus) do this for row variable only.

Comment: No changes, its still gives me data_url. the Django URL tag isn't passing.

Comment: console the value of `data_url` and also show me the change you did replacing of double quotes.

Comment: Its console logging the correct url, just not passing the value to data-url

Comment: data_url = '{% url 'leads:lead_edit' 1 %}'.replace(1, b["pk"])

Comment: It is also passing the same pk value for all rows

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve with:

```
function putTableData(response) {
let row;
$("#table_body").html("");
if (response["data"].length > 0) {
    $.each(response["data"], function (a, b) {
        row = `<tr>
                    <td>${b["first_name"]} ${b["last_name"]}</td                               
                    <td>${b["phone"]}</td>                   
                    <td>
                        <a data-url="/users/${b["pk"]}/edit">
                        </a>                     
                    </td>
                </tr>`;

            $("#table_body").append(row)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).